# sc: spreadsheet calculator, execute with a script

Tags: shell, sc

Suppose I have a bunch of "homegeneous" `sc`-files, and I need to execute one specific sequence of commands in each of them. Essentially, I need this:

```
for f in `ls *.sc`; do sc $f <do something>; done
```

In `<do something>`, I would like to supply a sequence of `sc` commands in a script. For starters, let it be something like, `for the cell Z9,
assign some text string`. The man-page does not feature a description of how this could be done; the online literature is scant, since `sc` is (unfortunately) not as popular as it (IMHO) deserves to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the docs more carefully, and understood that something of this kind can be done: 
`sc -v -WA0:D13 myfile.sc`.
This outputs to `stdin` the table contained in the range `A0:D13`.